# Place UL on right of SPAN

Tags: html, css

I need to have an UL on the right side of a SPAN (http://jsfiddle.net/Shg9L/8/).

When the width is not enough I would like the UL to keep being on the right side of the SPAN but the LI items to start stacking ...

The problem is that when I resize down the window the UL goes under the SPAN.

The code I currently have is (http://jsfiddle.net/Shg9L/8/):

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <span>Categories</span>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Book</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Computer</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tablet</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Toy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Audio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Game</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {.clear;}

div span {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;      
  float: left;
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  padding: 8px;  
}

div ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  .clear;    
}

div ul li {
  background-color: #F0F0F0;      
  float: left;
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  padding: 8px;  
}

.clear:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 2):

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shg9L/9/)

remove `float:left;` in your `div ul`

Comment: this works too, but he could write "categories" inside of a li too, and style it

Comment: This is not what I want ... I do not want the items to be under "Categories" span ... And in this case it happens ... Basically I want two columns without using a table ... Any idea?

Comment: @MDMoura : just an example for two columns without using a table... http://jsfiddle.net/Shg9L/34/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `div {white-space:nowrap;}` to make sure it doesn't break on the contents of the div. The `ul` has `display:inline-block;` instead of `float: left;`. Float left makes it go to the left, leaving the flow of the text, and inline-block still keeps it in the flow of the text, while not taking up a new line.

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shg9L/10/)

Comment: In fact your example does not work well ... Some words get hidden on the right of the window when resizing .. any idea why?

Comment: Maybe try to remove the white-space nowrap property

Comment: Reading your comment below, you want the items to break, but that the next line doesn't start under 'categories', but under book. Try to wrap them in a div then. I will make an example of this when back at my computer